# show label after clearing field value

Tags: jquery, html, css, placeholder

```
<form>
    <div class="fieldWrap">
           <label for="jobnamesurname">Name &amp; Surname</label>
           <input type="text" id="jobnamesurname" name="Name &amp; Surname">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="reset" name="reset">    
        </div>        
</form>
```

here is my [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/944/)

All works ok, just one thing - when you write something then click clear, it is ok, but after this when you try to write something label stays and both value and label are showing, I want to get rid of this issue.3.

I can't use just placeholder attribute because it doesn't work on IE9.

Comment: On chrome 43.0.2357.134 m I don't have this issue

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `placeholder` attribute?!  http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/945/  And ya, cannot replicate issue on chrome too

Comment: Yes why not just use the placeholder="Name &amp; Surname" and remove that label

Comment: Sorry if only me that couldn't see the bug.

Comment: I can't use just placeholder because I need to make work it on IE 9 @Vanojx1

Comment: Bug occurs on Chrome **43.0.2357.134 m** (Win 7)

Comment: Yes because I am using labels that bug is everywhere, in every browser. I am trying to solve this. Because placeholder isn't working on IE9. But I need to make it  work on IE9.@Zeratops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/2tyv5rh2/)

```
jQuery(".clearField").click(function(){
    var inputVal = jQuery(".fieldWrap input").val();
    if(inputVal != ''){
        jQuery(".fieldWrap input").val('');
        jQuery(".fieldWrap").removeClass('placeholder-hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think both problems can be solved using the [Placeholders.js Plugin](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/). It's lightweight, easy to use, and works just like the placeholder attribute except its suitable for IE6 and up.

Answer (score 1):

well i've just upded your fiddle, seems to work

```
jQuery(".clearField").click(function(){
    var inputVal = jQuery(".fieldWrap input").val();
    if(inputVal != ''){
        jQuery(".fieldWrap input").val('');
        //jQuery(".fieldWrap").addClass('showPlText');
        jQuery(".fieldWrap input").blur();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/951/

```
 jQuery(".clearField").click(function(){
   jQuery(".fieldWrap input").val('');
   jQuery('.fieldWrap > input').blur();  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {  
  $("#input_1").focus(function() {
    $("#label_1").hide(0);
  });
  
  $("#input_1").blur(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      $("#label_1").show(0); 
    }
  });
  
  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#input_1").val("");
    $("#input_1").blur();
    $("#label_1").show(0);
  });
});
```

```css
/* style the input */
.input_text {
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  width : 150px;
  z-index : 1;
  background : transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #0b4b84;
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;border : solid 1px black;
}


/* style the label "placeholder" */
.label {
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  z-index : 0;
  width : 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
    font-family:'Arial';
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

/* style the parent container of label/input */
.parent {
  background : lightgrey; 
  display : inline-block;
  position : relative;
  width : 600px;
  background : #FFF; /* move background here */
}

/* style for reset button */
.button-reset {
  margin-top : 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" class="input_text" id="input_1" />
  <label class="label" id="label_1">Name & Surname</label>
  <button id="reset" class="button-reset">Réinitialiser</button>
</div>
```

I think you were trying something similar. I used JQuery plain as it offers IE 6+ compatibility, and I used `position : absolute;` for both the `<input type="text" />` and `<label></label>` to peform this trick.